# What ins the derivative of \int_0^t\varphi(t,u)du

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(t)=\int_0^t\varphi(t,u)du$ where $\varphi$ is a continuos function. Do yo know how to compute the derivative of f?
It is not possible to directly apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Do you mean the derivative of $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant the derivative of $f$ in your post.

In a simple setting we need some assumptions on $\varphi$ namely that $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}$ exists and is continuous (to simplify things). Then the derivative of $f$ is obtained by
$$f'(t)=\int_0^t \dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}(t,u)\,du+\varphi(t,t)$$
We get two bits, in the first one we differentiate under the integral sign while the second looks like an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Note that the integral above is well-defined since $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}$ is continuous.

Comment: You mean $\varphi(t,t)$ and $\varphi(t,0)$. But the last one should not appear in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I'll correct.

Comment: I don't understand why you write $\varphi(t,0)$. In a single variable the theorem States that $d/dt \int_0^t f(u)du= f(t)$. The value of $f$ at the initial point doesn't matter.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't be there. I wrongly applied a more general result where the bounds of the integral are two functions $g(t)$ and $h(t)$, then you get one term for each bound.

Comment: Okey. Perfect. :)